# Creating either a jQuery Object or Multidimensional array. Then searching within it to give a response

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, vbscript

I'm writing a small web app for work, they are very outdated and won't budge in regards to updating anything so I have to work with what is there.

what I have is a database with several columns (lets call them one, two, three, four) and I have to cross reference a set of variables against one, two and three in order to give me four.

normally I would do this in VBscript and SQL like so

```
SQL="SELECT four FROM table WHERE one='"&a&"', AND two='"&b&"' AND three='"&c&"';"
```

This would give me the value of column four.

However I need to get this information browser side.

I've resorted to the following

```
<%
SQL="SELECT one, two, three, four FROM table;"
set rs=MyConn.execute(SQL)
%>
<script>
var ratios = [<%do while not rsTimes.eof%>
{ 
    "one": "<%=rs("one")%>",
    "two": "<%=rs("two")%>", 
    "three": "<%=rs("three")%>", 
    "four": "<%=rs("four")%>" 
},
<%rs.MoveNext
loop%>{ 
    "one": "end", 
    "two": "end", 
    "three": "end", 
    "four": "end" 
}
];
</script>
```

as far as I can tell by looking at the source of the outputted asp page this has created a multidimensional array.

But i'm not sure how to search for it like I would have if it were an SQL database.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have an array of objects.

To loop through it use:

```
var output = '';

for(var i=0; i < ratios.length; i++)
{
   var ratio = ratios[i];
   if(ratio.one == a && ratio.two == b && ratio.three == c)
   {
      output = ratio.four;
      break; // Once found, exit for-loop
   }     
}
```

You can do more advanced and even SQL-like searches using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.
how would I use the result though?
four actually contains a number that I'll be using further down in the page.
to elaborate more, I need to be able to specify what "one" "two" and "three" are (I plan on doing this by declaring variables above) and then it should give me what "four" is based on those conditions.
"one" "two" and "three" will always give me a unique "four" base on the data I have in the database if that makes sense

Comment: I don't know what you need to do with the results.

Comment: how would I make "four" into a variable that I can then use.
example: var output = "four"

Comment: so I would ned the following (assuming a b and c are the variables I've already declared?
var output = '';

for(var i=0; i < ratios.length; i++)
{
   var ratio = ratios[i];
   if(ratio.one === "a")
   {
   }
   else if(ratio.two === "b")
   {
   } 
   else if(ratio.three === "c")
   {
      output = ratio.four;
      break; // Once found, exit for-loop
   }     
}

Comment: if three == "c", then get the value of four. Is that what need?

Comment: if (ratio.one == a) { if (ratio.two == b) { (if (ratio.three == c) { output = ratio.four; }}}
if that makes sence.
so basically if all the first three are true then it gives me the value of four

Comment: thanks a lot for that buddy, it pushed me in the right direction and I can now crack on :)